# react hooks question: simple content filter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Novice question here, new to hooks and React, I want to be able to click a filter button in the Nav component and show only that category of divs in the App component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-menu-react-cbwhk

what's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this also...just check your condition in map function.
https://lcizy.csb.app/

```
export default function App() {
  const data = ["dog", "cat", "lizard", "dog", "cat", "dog", "lizard", "dog"];
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  function filterTags(val) {
    setFilter(val);
  }
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav filter={filter} setFilter={filterTags} />
      {data.map((x, i) =>
        filter === x || filter === "all" ? (
          <div key={i} data-tags={x} style={styles}>
            {x}
          </div>
        ) : null
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live working solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-menu-react-lcizy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: perfect!! thank you Vahid! Both of these solutions work but this is a touch more readable to me as a beginner, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow filter function [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) Solution:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Nav from "./Nav";

const styles = {
  padding: "10px",
  margin: "5px",
  background: "gold",
  width: "100px",
  height: "100px",
  display: "inline-block"
};

export default function App() {
  const data = ["dog", "cat", "lizard", "dog", "cat", "dog", "lizard", "dog"];
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  //what I'm having trouble with:

  // function filterTags(filter){data.map(x => {
  //   if(x.dataset.tags.includes("filter")){
  //   return (
  //       <div data-tags={x} style={styles}>
  //         {x}
  //       </div>
  //     );
  //   })
  // }
  // };
  console.log(filter)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav filter={filter} setFilter={setFilter} />
      {/* {filterTags(filter)} */}
      {/* only show the filtered divs */}
      {data.filter(_ => filter === _).map((x,i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i} data-tags={x} style={styles}>
            {x}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!